# Excepción ''System.StackOverflowException"

Tags: c#, excepciones

Me genera esta excepcion en mi cadena de conexion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otra clase llamada `BusquedaModulo` donde hago uso de esta clase `ConexionBD`, y despues ya en el windows form creo un objeto `BusquedaModulo` y lo pongo donde me interesa, pero al correrlo me sale esto.

Tengo entendido que algo sobre el desvordamiento

Esta es la clase `BusquedaModulo`:

```
private ConexionBD conexion = new ConexionBD();
private SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();

public void buscarModulos()
{            
    SqlDataAdapter datos = new SqlDataAdapter("select c.id_parteM,describpM,precio,bom from modelo_modulos a inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM where a.id_modeloM ='" + txtBuscar.Text + "'", conexion.abrirConexion());
    DataSet sd = new DataSet();
    datos.Fill(sd, "modelo_modulos");
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = sd.Tables[0];
    this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 70;
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 220;
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Numero de Parte";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Precio";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "BOM";
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (1 + i).ToString();
    }
    comando.Connection = conexion.abrirConexion();
    comando.CommandText = "select a.describeM from modelo_modulos a inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM where a.id_modeloM ='" + txtBuscar.Text + "'";
    SqlDataReader rd = comando.ExecuteReader();
    lblDescripcion.Text = "";
    if (rd.Read())
    {
        lblDescripcion.Text = rd["describeM"] as string;
    }
    conexion.cerrarConexion();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El exception se genera porque estas creando demasiados objetos de conexion sin administrarlos de forma correcta, la conexion no se define de forma global, debe estar dentro de un bloque `using` que permita su correcta destruccion cuando no se use y ademas permita a `ado.net` adeministrar el `pool de conexiones`.

No tiene sentido definir una clase para solo aisgnar el `connection string` al `SqlConnection`

```
public class ConexionBD
{
    public static string CadenaConexion = "....";
}
```

entonces usarla

```
public void buscarModulos()
{
    string connstring = ConexionBD.CadenaConexion;

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = @"select c.id_parteM,describpM,precio,bom 
                            from modelo_modulos a 
                            inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM 
                            inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM 
                            where a.id_modeloM = @filtro";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filtro", txtBuscar.Text);

        SqlDataAdapter datos = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        datos.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        SetDataGridView(DataGridView1);


        string query2 = @"select a.describeM 
                        from modelo_modulos a 
                        inner join union_modulos b on a.id_modeloM = b.id_modeloM 
                        inner join partes_modulos c on b.id_parteM = c.id_parteM 
                        where a.id_modeloM = @filtro";
        SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
        comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filtro", txtBuscar.Text);

        var rd = comando2.ExecuteReader();
        lblDescripcion.Text = "";
        if (rd.Read())
        {
            lblDescripcion.Text = rd["describeM"].ToString();
        }

    }
}


private void SetDataGridView(DataGridView1 grid)
{
    grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    grid.Columns[0].Width = 70;
    grid.Columns[2].Width = 220;
    grid.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Numero de Parte";
    grid.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
    grid.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Precio";
    grid.Columns[4].HeaderText = "BOM";
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        grid.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (1 + i).ToString();
    }
}
```

La idea seria

- definir la conexion en un bloque `using`
- usar siempre parametros, no se concatenen en un string lo que quieres filtrar
- no necesitas el close de la conexion si esta dentro del using, este se encarga de destruir el objeto y liberar memoria o de reutilizarlo